# My pip is displaying an invalid version option error

Tags: python, pip

```
D:\PyCharm Projects>pip install pygame

Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

20.2.2 is not a valid value for version option, please specify a boolean value like yes/no, true/false or 1/0 instead.
```

Every time I try to use pip at all, it runs this error and does nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Might be an issue with the path and non-matching pip and python execs. Try `python -m pip install pygame`

Comment: What is the version of _pip_? Is that the full command input and terminal output?

Answer (score -1):

[It may be worth it to check pip documentation.] [1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables)

I would try with `pip3 install pygame`

If it doesn't work, please try to create virtual env and then install pygame. Fresh installation of python may help as well. Try to keep it clean in the future to prevent conflicts.

```
# do this in your root/ project folder directory

python -m venv pygame_env

pygame_env\Scripts\activate

pip install pygame
```

**EDIT**

Try update pip

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

or

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user
```

Comment: Both of the solutions you offered ran the same error, and I already tried a fresh installation of python. I tried to independently install pip as well, but the same thing happened.

Comment: pip install pygame 1

Comment: Using pip to solve this won't work, because I can't use pip. It says there's something wrong with the version argument, so it could be something in the setup files of pip?